# Setting position for prompt in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can I set the position for the output prompt in Visual Studio 2008 when debugging is started?

I have two screens and I want the prompt to always appear on my second screen so that I still can see the code on the primary screen, I have tried some tricks but I haven't got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "outputprompt". If you are creating a command line application and are talking about the command window, then

1. position the window where you want it (you can pause you app if it closes too fast)
2. click on its system menu, then click on properties
3. on the third tab of the appearing properties dialog, enter the values you like (be sure to uncheck automatic window positioning)
4. close the dialog by clicking OK
5. in the dialog that appears, pick the option that changes the link, instead of just changing the current window (I'm not sure either a German or English translation of the options is helpful for you)

HTH.